# Kotlin PendingIntent with FLAG_IMMUTABLE does't work with exoplayer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-pendingintent, exoplayer, flags

I'am using a pending intent to make a notification bar when i play a song in my music app. it used to work perfectly but i have to update my targetSdk to 31 and i run into an error telling me that i need to use some flag with my pendingIntent :

```
Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

Problem is that i use this flag when i declare my pending intent :

```
 val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        applicationContext,
    0,
        packageManager?.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
```

So i don't get why it say that i need to use the flag when i already using it ? Am I missing something ?

**EDIT**

```
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4953)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2300)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: info.cairn.pro: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:382)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:673)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:660)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager.createBroadcastIntent(PlayerNotificationManager.java:1601)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager.createPlaybackActions(PlayerNotificationManager.java:1557)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager.<init>(PlayerNotificationManager.java:862)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager.<init>(PlayerNotificationManager.java:793)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager.<init>(PlayerNotificationManager.java:757)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel(PlayerNotificationManager.java:729)
        at com.viapresse.presskit.exoplayer.MusicNotificationManager.<init>(MusicNotificationManager.kt:29)
        at com.viapresse.presskit.exoplayer.MusicService.onCreate(MusicService.kt:114)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4940)
```

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace

Comment: Your error says it is coming from ExoPlayer. What version of ExoPlayer are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.14.1 on exoplayer, i ll try to update it and see where it goes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by @ianhanniballake, the crash was happening in the exoplayer dependency and not in my code...

So i went on https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/RELEASENOTES.md to check all exoplayer update and i found out where they implemented PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE funny thing it on 2.14.2 just one iteration above the one i was using.

So i updated the dependency to exoplayer and everything work.